# How to tell csquotes to italicize quotes?

Tags: italic, csquotes

I have a *very* stubborn professor who requires italicized quotes.

So I have a document full of quotes, labeled with `\enquote{}`. How can I easily change all of them to be in italic ?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation or anywhere else...

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[singletitle=true, isbn=false, backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=verbose-trad2, citestyle=verbose-trad2]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

I like trains, so does my mom. She said : \enquote{I like trains !} 

\end{document}
```

I could just add `\textit` inside `\enquote` (I think), but I have hundreds of quotes,...

Comment: Define italic quotes

Comment: Even better please also provide a sample document so we know which preamble we have to work with

Comment: By italic quote, I mean that the quoted text, inside the \enquote{}, is in italic. I'm adding a sample right now.

Comment: There are no official hooks for `\enquote` IIRC…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change the french style. But be aware that \enquote could e.g. be used in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{french}
  {\itshape\mkfrenchopenquote{\guillemotleft}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\guillemotright}}
  {\itshape\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
\begin{document}

I like trains, so does my mom. She said : \enquote{I like trains !} clclc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both of your solutions fit perfectly ! Is there a way to apply the same treatment to the quote environment ?

Comment: It is only one solution, the first \itshape is for inner quotes and `\enquote*{..}`.

Answer (score 5):

Does this suit you?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
% erased not relevant packages
\newcommand*{\myenquote}[1]{\enquote{{\itshape#1}}}
\begin{document}
   I like trains, so does my mom. She said: \myenquote{I like trains !}
\end{document}
```

And just replace all `enquote` occurances with `myenquote` in your doc (be careful not to change the first one at the preamble!).

Comment: Seems to work as well ! Thanks for your input !

Comment: And the main text will by hyphenated in French, punctuation in French style, ... Not good.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
% erased not relevant packages
\let\oldenquote\enquote
\renewcommand{\enquote}[1]{{\itshape\oldenquote{#1}}}
\begin{document}
   I like trains, so does my mom. She said: \enquote{I like trains !}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives a italic closing quote but an upright opening quote.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I see. This was my first step in world of csquotes, so I wasn't enough careful about languages differences. Thank you for point.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , actually I forgot to activatet franch babel. Doing this, I receive the same result as you in your answer.

Comment: No, I didn't complain about the type of the quote sign, but the italic/upright mix. Look closely at the opening guillemets: Yours is upright as the \itshape is inserted *after* the quote sign, but the closing guillemets is slanted.

Comment: I'm really novice and clumsy in this csquotes .... I'm now correct my answer again (just interchanging order of commands) , hopefully this time will be correct. Thank you very much for pointing to weakness of my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

might be a little late to the party but

```
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\let\itenquote\enquote
\renewcommand*{\enquote}[1]{\itenquote{{\itshape#1}}}
```

did the trick just fine for me

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, can you put a compilable complete code with the output please of your answer?