# Quote inline with italics

Tags: italic, quoting, csquotes

I am trying to quote a sentence in line and to have it in italics so like " bla bla bla " and the text inside the quotation marks is in italic.
How to do that?

Comment: a quick and dirty solution is `\`\`\textit{bla bla bla}''`... but I think it is not the answer you're looking for. Maybe more context and a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help us help you?!

Comment: Are you using `csquotes`, as the tag implies? With the `\enquote` macro? A minimal example as ebo asked for would make this entirely clear.

Comment: if so, you can try `\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}
  {\itshape\textquotedblleft}
  [\textquotedblleft]
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}` (I've found this solution on this site, but cannot find again whom I should give proper credit)

Answer (score 5):

This solution is simply the adaptation to the `english` option of the `babel` package of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280628/64454) written by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}

    %Beginning of the interresting part
    \DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}
        {\itshape\textquotedblleft}
        [\textquotedblleft]
        {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
        {\textquoteleft}
        {\textquoteright}
    %End of the interresting part

\begin{document}
        I want to say: \enquote{Hello world!}, but I'm a bit shy, so I wrote it down.
\end{document}
```

[image]